# some pointers on a php mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to start connecting php to my sql. I have a database created in phpmyadmin named 'snr' and that has a table named 'donate' which has four columns named 'user_ID', 'first_Name', 'last_Name' and donate_TOTAL.

When i run the following script in a browser I get the while loop showing and therefore nothing is returned via the echo statements. I want to show first_Name + last_Name.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("snr", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM donate WHERE user_ID > 0");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['first_Name'] . " " . $row['last_Name'];
echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what is returned when i run it in a broswer.

```
0"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo $row['first_Name'] . " " .     $row['last_Name']; echo "
"; } mysql_close($con); ?>
```

Comment: wat do you mean by u ran it in a browser?!!

Comment: It appears that your server isn't recognizing and parsing it as a php page ... is the file extension .php? Can you execute other php files?

Comment: yes other php files are fine and its saved as php in my server directory using WAMP. All other php files work fine.

Comment: I also feel PHP is the root of the problem here. put echo '>'; right after your <?php tag, my guess is that it'll write out the rest of that script.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand that last comment.

Comment: What is the filename that it's saved under?

Comment: mikeoermans is suggesting the the ">" character is breaking out of your PHP syntax in this line: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM donate WHERE user_ID > 0");`. That's what the output suggests too, since everything after the ">" character is printed. try creating a new php page, and put this: `<?php echo '>'; ?> to see if you get a '>' rather than at '>'; ?>

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("snr", $con);

$result = mysql_query("'SELECT * FROM donate WHERE user_ID > 0'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['first_Name'] . " " . $row['last_Name'];
echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```